# in unity engine player is flipping continuously when i use "transform.Rotate(0f,180f,0f);

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

sorry for bad english

hey guys Iam using `transform.rotate(0f,180f,0f);` to flip the player when facing left

but in game view, while playing, the player is flipping left to right continuously i.e he is going from 0 to 180 and coming back to 0 and it goes on.... does any one know anything about it?
& thanks in advance

Comment: yes .. `Rotate` does what it name says: rotate the object by a certain angle ... you are every frame rotating ("flipping") your object by 180° ... in general please post complete minimal working code examples

Answer (score 0):

Using `Transform.Rotate()` will rotate the player. If you do it in the Update method, it will continuously rotate it. What you are trying to accomplish is trying to set the rotation. You can do this using `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);`

Comment: thank you luemus ill give this a try  ,and can i ask why would this happen? cause i have it under if ,else conditions ,only calls if the key is pressed

Comment: Assume that the game is running and you are holding the button. Let's say that game is running on 30 frames per second. That means the update gets called 30 times. Now, since you are holding the button, transform.Rotate() gets called 30 times, which means you rotate your player 180 degrees 30 times every second. You could use Input.GetKeyDown instead of Input.GetKey, and it will only rotate the player the update you pressed the key.

Comment: it happens even when im idle ,while no key is being pressed , idk whats wrong i saw some tutorial it was working great for them, and btw i tried ur suggestion and it is rotating the sprite but not the actual axis , am making shooter so is there any other thing i can try?

Comment: I need to see your code before making any more assumptions.